# Impacto de performance usando mixins em um sistema de grid CSS

Tags: css, grid

Suponha que você queira construir sua própria grid e que ao contrário da que pode ser encontrada no *Bootstrap*, você quer fazer algo semântico. Para isso você escreve `mixins` com a sintaxe do *SCSS*.

Vamos supor que você tenha algo assim:

```
@mixin coluna($col){
  width: calc( ((100% * ($col)) / 12) - (2 * $col-marging) );
  margin: $col-marging;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

E então quando quer usar em algum elemento, é só chamar o `coluna`, assim:

```
.logo{
  @include coluna(1);
}
```

O problema é que toda vez que fizer isso (e fará para vários elementos da página), o CSS processado vai ter um ganho de 4 linhas por elemento. Se você usar isso 20 elementos já são 80 linhas a mais de código (sem falar no cálculo que está sendo feito cujo impacto na performance eu desconheço completamente).

Algumas pessoas dizem que isso é uma ideia ruim e outras que é uma boa prática para manter o código semântico. Mas qual é o impacto real dessa abordagem em particular para criação de *grids*?

Comment: Então entenda que o código SASS irá ser "transpilado" para CSS, você pode utilizar webpack, grunt, gulp ou até um CLI (linha de comando) para fazer isso. O foco é a velocidade de desenvolvimento, a "transpilação" acontece quando você fizer alteração. Nenhum navegador entende SASS, Stylus, Less, etc... Navegadores entendem JS, CSS e HTML.